# Usando ForeignKey para salvar no BD Django

Tags: banco-de-dados, django, relacionamento, chave-estrangeira

Não consigo fazer a relação de Data com Professor, tenho que salvar Professor e passar o seu id para Data chave estrangeira e salvar, quando executo o codigo o id não é passado

**forms.py**

```
class ProfessorForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(ProfessorForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['nome'].widget.attrs['placeholder'] = 'Professor'

    class Meta:
        model = Professor
        fields = '__all__'

class DataForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Data
        fields = '__all__'
```

**views.py**

```
def home(request):
    context = {}
    template_name = 'envelope/cad_professor.html'
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ProfessorForm(request.POST)
        data = DataForm()
        if form.is_valid():
            data.form = form
            form.save()
            data.save()
            context['success'] = True
            return redirect (views.home)
    else:
       form = ProfessorForm()
    context['form'] = form
    return render(request,template_name , context)
```

**PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO**

```
data.save()
new_form = form.save(commit = False)
new_form.data = data
new_form.save()
```

Comment: Como estão os seus models?

Comment: `data.form = form` não é assim que é feito uma relação. Além disso você deveria explicar na pergunta o que é esse model `Data` e qual o campo que está sendo relacionado, do jeito que está é insuficiente para resolver o seu problema. Coloque pelo menos os campos do model Data e Professor para que se possa resolver sua questão.